# Unable to run the GridSearchCV function

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, gridsearchcv

I am building a ML model for predicting a binary target variable. When building the Random Forest, I an wanting to run the GridSearchCV() to be able to cross-validate my results.
I have imported all of the necessary libraries.
It gives me the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/6s/sjprd_n541b06ly63j2zcbg40000gn/T/ipykernel_15789/3909671296.py in <module>
      9 
     10 start=time.time()
---> 11 rfc_grid_search = GridSearchCV(param_grid, cv=10, 
     12                               scoring='f1_macro',
     13                               return_train_score=True,njobs=-1)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'njobs'
```

```
#random forest

param_grid = [
    {
        'rfc__n_estimators': [100, 200, 500],
        'rfc__max_depth': [5, None]
    },
]

start=time.time()
rfc_grid_search = GridSearchCV(param_grid, cv=10, 
                              scoring='f1_macro',
                              return_train_score=True,njobs=-1)

rfc_grid_search.fit(X_train, Y_train)

end = (time.time() - start)/3600
print(f"Took {end} hours")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using `GrideSearchCV` from `sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV`.

If so you should use `n_jobs` instead of `njobs`.